# Inserting table data into a DB ignores !empty check and still inserts

Tags: php, html

I have multiple tables that a user can enter data into. If the user chooses they don't have to enter data into every table and I have checks to see if the fields are empty before iterating through the data and begin to insert it into the DB.

Here is what one of the tables looks like:

```
<table id="budget_table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Roofs</th>
        <th>Area</th>
        <th>Recommendation</th>
        <th>Budget</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="budget_tb">
    <tr id="budget_row0">
        <td><input id="budget-roofs" name="budget-roofs[]" placeholder="Entire Roof Area"></td>
        <td><input id="budget-area" name="budget-roof-area[]" placeholder="Approx. 1,000 Sq. Ft."></td>
        <td><input id="budget-recommendation" name="budget-recommendation[]" placeholder="Roof Repairs & Maintenance"></td>
        <td><input id="budget-amount" name="budget-amount[]" placeholder="$1,500.00 to $2,500.00"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit">
```

When the user clicks submit I will then check to see if the first input field is empty, if it is empty I want to do nothing. If it has something within the input fields then I want to dump that data into a DB.

Here is what my PHP looks like:

```
var_dump($_POST['budget-roofs']); //I added this to see what was going on

if(!empty($_POST['budget-roofs'])){ 
    //foreach budget row insert data
    foreach ($_POST['budget-roofs'] as $index => $roofs) {
        $area = $_POST['budget-roof-area'][$index];
        $recommendations = $_POST['budget-recommendation'][$index];
        $amount = $_POST['budget-amount'][$index];

        //insert queries
    }
}
```

If I enter nothing within my input fields it submits an empty string into my DB.

I used var_dump to check to see if it really is empty and perhaps why it is ignoring my check. This is what I am being shown:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
```

So it shows that I have a size of 1 (so its not empty which is why my check is being ignored).

However I am unsure as to why it has an empty string?

I tried taking out my `placeholder` attribute because I thought maybe that was causing something but that was not the issue either.

Is there a better way to check to see if to see if my input field  is empty and ensure that empty strings don't get dumped into the db?

Where is that empty string coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I am unsure as to why it has an empty string?

The input fields in the form is submitted and if they contain no data (entered by user) they are submitted empty.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>

<form method="post" action="example.php">
    <input type="text" name="arr" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If you submit the form above empty:

```
array(2) { ["arr"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

You have at least one array element of the budget-roofs since it's present in the form. `<input id="budget-roofs" name="budget-roofs[]" placeholder="Entire Roof Area">` If you do not enter the input it is still being submitted empty.

> Is there a better way to check to see if to see if my input field is
>   empty and ensure that empty strings don't get dumped into the db?

You have to check each element individually.

```
foreach ($_POST['budget-roofs'] as $index => $roofs) {
   if (! empty($roofs) 
     // Insert here. But remember to check the other fields, they may be empty as well.
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I was unaware that it submits an empty string - I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days. You sir are a saviour - Thank you!